# How to setup MVC 5 unobtrusive validation correctly when appending the form from an AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

I have googeld about this issue and I have checked my web.config, bundleconfig and my layout which look like this:
 web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

In my App_Start folder under "BundleConfig.cs":

> ```
>         var jqueryBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery");
>         jqueryBundle.Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js");
>         jqueryBundle.Include("~/Scripts/moment.min.js");
>         jqueryBundle.Include("~/Scripts/loadingoverlay.js");
>         jqueryBundle.Include("~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js");
>         jqueryBundle.Include("~/Scripts/lang-all.js");
>         jqueryBundle.Transforms.Add(jsTransformer);
>         jqueryBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
>         bundles.Add(jqueryBundle);
> ```
>
> var jqueryvalBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval");
>               jqueryvalBundle.Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate*");
>               jqueryvalBundle.Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js");
>               jqueryvalBundle.Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js");
>               jqueryvalBundle.Transforms.Add(jsTransformer);
>               jqueryvalBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
>               bundles.Add(jqueryvalBundle);

in my layout page:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

Firebug shows:

[image]

Thus far everything is included and shouold be running smoothly.

My model:

```
   [DisplayName("Förnamn")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vänligen ange ett förnamn")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Efternamn")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vänligen ange ett efternamn")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("E-post")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vänligen ange epost")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Ange en korrekt e-postaddress")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Mobil")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string PhoenNumber { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Lösenord")]
    public string PassWord { get; set; }
```

My view:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "credentialsForm" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group createCustomerFormGroup">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @name = "FirstName" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group createCustomerFormGroup">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group createCustomerFormGroup">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group createCustomerFormGroup">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PassWord, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PassWord, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PassWord, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group createCustomerFormGroup">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoenNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoenNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoenNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
</div>
```

a field in the form via firebug:
[image]

I run this script in firebug and I get no errors even though there should be errors since some of the fields are requiered but they do not have a value:

```
$("#credentialsForm").validate().numberOfInvalids()
// retunrs 0

$("#credentialsForm").validate().valid()
// returns true
```

Ive been at this for hours and im going nuts right now, what am I missing?

EDIT: changed the question from "How to setup MVC 5 unobtrusive validation correctly" to it's current title since it described what I was looking for better than the previous title.

Comment: When the page is rendered open the browser editor and check if the html validation rules are generated?

Comment: I assum you are referig to this:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/NDZbE.png

Picture is also in the question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some time I figured this out.

I was appending this form from an AJAX call which returned a partial view.

I found the answer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321040/unobtrusive-validation-not-working-on-dynamically-added-partial-view)

apperently when adding dynamic data like this you first have to strip the form of 'validator' and 'unobtrusiveValidation'and then call the $.validator.unobtrusive.parse function on the form, like so:

```
var form = $("#main_div").closest("form");
form.removeData('validator');
form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
```

A more detailed explenation can be found [here](http://www.mfranc.com/javascript/unobtrusive-validation-in-partial-views/)